# Latest dependency versions of various Apache libraries from maven suddenly use a very old version

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, apache-commons

So I've been using various `Apache commons` libraries for a while and all was fine until suddenly when using the `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` command or the `LATEST` version tag uses/places a very old version of various Apache libraries into the `<version>` tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>20030805.205232</version> <!-- Note: 2003! -->
</dependency>
```

If we take a look at the [`maven repository`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net) of `commons-net`, we can tell that this is one of the first releases of the library. Why am I not getting the latest version as requested anymore? What happened? This is annoying because my code of course fails to compile with such an old version and I have to manually go through my dependencies and update the versions for each malbehaving `Apache` library. Strangely enough, it does not affect libraries by other vendors.

```
>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T17:06:16+02:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_271, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Based on your example `https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%20commons-net%20AND%20a:commons-net`  is the newest one with those coordinates and with the given version `20030805.205232` is greater than `3.7.2` ... the comparison is correct and the result is correct. Unfortunately it is not what you might expect or would like to get. I strongly recommend to avoid the usage of  `LATEST` version marker which is deprecated for a long time and since Maven 3.5.3 this produces a [WARNING](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.3/release-notes.html) The comparison is done on the version not on the date.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Agreed, it's time to get it go. Thanks for the explanation. It's still ironic that `Apache` themselves screws up the proper functionality of their `latest-versions` feature due to their library versioning policy for some `commons` libraries. Why wouldn't they just use the release date for picking the latest version to make this feature meaninful again?

Comment: You have to be aware that Apache Maven and Apache Commons are two different projects also all projects not only Apache projects learned over the time that time based versions are a bad idea see semver.org. And the `latest-version` feature of the Apache Project not an Apache feature is Apache Maven. I would expect that in particular commons project would go to the correct groupId like `org.apache.commons.net` etc. or something `org.apache.commons`... to make it better some of them already did that .. but not all https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.apache.commons

Comment: You should also see that Apache is a foundation which comprises of 350+ projects, 8000+ committers (https://www.apache.org/) I suggest to upgrade your entry to the most recent version manually...