# Why Maven Resolving RELEASE Version To Very First Version

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I did research to find the answer for this question but failed hence putting it here.

We have this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This used to work for so many year, but suddenly, today, it stopped working. By not working I mean today it is trying to resolve to very first version of commons-io i.e. **20030203.000550**
I can not find out what version '**RELEASE**' version used to fetch before today but it used to fetch newer version than **20030203.000550** as we have been using some methods from newer version that is not present in **20030203.000550**
Can someone help me understand why '**RELEASE**' fetching very first version.

Please note that This problem is not just my machine, everybody from my organisation facing this problem with **RELEASE** version. Also we have not upgraded maven version. We have been using maven 3 for long time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65188179/296328

Answer (score 0):

Using `RELEASE` is deprecated.

My advice: Set `<version>` to the version you need. For updates, use the `versions-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Yes we now changed to latest version, but my question is why suddenly it stopped working?